# Route Webservice response to a POJO without implementing any camel specific interface

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I am routing my webservice request to a bean which sends the response back to the service.

```
<camel:from uri="cxf:bean:authTest" />
<camel:to uri="bean:routeExitResponseProcessor"/>
```

Now in the bean class I have to implement **Processor** interface, access the **Exchange** object , call the implementation method and then send the response back to the client by setting the response object to exchange's body.

Can I get rid of all the Camel specific java code and configure everything in my applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the bean component you do not have to implement the Processor interface.
If your class simply has one public method then it will be called and camel will try to convert the incoming body to your parameter and process the return as new body.

Try with a method like:

WebServiceResult myMethod(WebServiceInput input) {...}

Where the Parameters are those generated from the wsdl.

Christian